# Values are not mapped to the POJO class with ObjectMapper in Java even though it is present in JSON

Tags: java, graphql, jackson, objectmapper

These are the values from the input JSON to be mapped to the POJO class.

```
   "{"data":{"getUserInformation":{"CreationDate":"22.07.2021 10:24:53","Email":"test@b.de","User":{"UserName":"testUser20SK","LoggingEnabled":null},"State":"FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD","Verified":true}}}"
```

The mapping logic is as below:

```
 String response = appsyncGraphQLClient.execute(HttpMethodName.POST, new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes())).getBody();
            JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response).path("data").path("getUserInformation");
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            objectMapper.treeToValue(data,CognitoUser.class);
```

I am not getting any values in the POJO from the JSON. All the variables are showing as null. What could be I am missing here?

My POJO CLass is generated from auto gen feature from a Graphql schema

```
type CognitoUser {
    CreationDate: String
    Email: String!
    State: String
    User: User
    Username: String!
    Verified: Boolean
}
```

POJO Class

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(
    value = "com.kobylynskyi.graphql.codegen.GraphQLCodegen",
    date = "2021-07-22T13:02:27+0200"
)
public class CognitoUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String CreationDate;
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String Email;
    private String State;
    private User User;
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String Username;
    private Boolean Verified;

    public CognitoUser() {
    }

    public CognitoUser(String CreationDate, String Email, String State, User User, String Username, Boolean Verified) {
        this.CreationDate = CreationDate;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.State = State;
        this.User = User;
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Verified = Verified;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return CreationDate;
    }
    public void setCreationDate(String CreationDate) {
        this.CreationDate = CreationDate;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String Email) {
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }
    public void setState(String State) {
        this.State = State;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return User;
    }
    public void setUser(User User) {
        this.User = User;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public Boolean getVerified() {
        return Verified;
    }
    public void setVerified(Boolean Verified) {
        this.Verified = Verified;
    }
```

Edit:
I have found out what could be the problem but not able to get corerct solution

JsonNode is storing value under children like below: (Got this from debug)

```
result = {ObjectNode@3642} "{"CreationDate":"22.07.2021 10:24:53","Email":"test@lb.de","User":{"UserName":"testUser20SK","LoggingEnabled":null},"State":"FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD","Verified":true}"
 _children = {LinkedHashMap@4442}  size = 5
  "CreationDate" -> {TextNode@4452} ""22.07.2021 10:24:53""
  "Email" -> {TextNode@4454} ""test@lb.de""
  "User" -> {ObjectNode@4456} "{"UserName":"testUser20SK","LoggingEnabled":null}"
  "State" -> {TextNode@4458} ""FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD""
  "Verified" -> {BooleanNode@4460} "true"
 _nodeFactory = {JsonNodeFactory@4443}
```

I used  objectMapper.readValue(data.get("children").asText(),CognitoUser.class);`

but it is not giving result. `

Comment: can you add what that string `response` has?

Comment: You need to instruct `Jackson` to use properties instead of `getters/setters`. Another approach is to specify `@JsonProperty` over getter methods. For example: `@JsonProperty("CreationDate")`. See duplicated question and answers.